# Distribute session-only git configuration on ssh login

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, git, bash-alias

I have a bunch of development servers (linux) that I connect to via SSH from linux workstation. On most of these servers I want to use the Git command line interface. I use a set of Git aliases that I want to be available on all these servers after login. E.g. I only want to type "g s" instead of "git status".

Now I could setup these aliases on all these servers but this is not as comfortable as I would wish.

I want to setup all aliases (git aliases plus bash alias g=git) directly after logging in to the server. Best would be if it was only valid for the current session.

I already found a way to copy a file after the connection has started running with the "LocalCommand" option of ssh. But I would need to run this file on the remote side within the bash session I use.

Any hints how I could go?

Answer (score -1):

add a /path to aliases  in ~/.ssh_config

Something like:

```
/etc/.ssh/ssh_config
Host server1
 HostName server1.cyberciti.biz
 User nixcraft
 Port 4242
 IdentityFile /nfs/shared/users/nixcraft/keys/server1/id_rsa
 aliases_config_file /nfs/aliases/foo
```

Comment: "aliases_config_file" isn't a valid ssh configuration option as far as I'm aware. Could you edit your answer to indicate where you got this information?